# Firefox and Chrome use 100% CPU and load pages dreadfully slowly

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, cpu

I got a new ASUS laptop with Windows 10 preinstalled. Unfortunately, Google Chrome uses **100% of the CPU for 10-20 seconds** when I load some pages. Then CPU usage goes back to normal. I'm having the exact same issue with Firefox.

My old laptop (Windows 8.1) runs Google Chrome and Firefox just fine with a reasonably similar CPU.

How could I troubleshoot this?

I already tried a ton of solutions from Window's settings (power plan / optimize performance) to disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and Windows registry hacks but so far nothing made any difference whatsoever.

Comment: open a cmd as admin, run this **"C:\Windows\System32\wpr.exe" -start  CPU && timeout -1 "C:\Windows\System32\wpr.exe" -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl**, start Firefox/Chrome, open a page and when the site is loaded, go back to cmd and press a key to stop logging. zip the ETL + ngenpdb folder and share (onedrive, dropbox) the zip

Comment: have you captured the traces or is the issue gone?

Answer (score 0):

If you can not get an answer;-
Maxthon Browser in Google's Playstore is a "light" browser that shares favorites, even open tabs amongst devices with a sign-in and cloud storage.
I'm currently using their next generation browser (alpha release) that works only in Windows 10/Android/iOS enviroments.
I noticed a great improvement using this browser in Windows 7, and it does still work in Windows 10, even though this alpha release MX5 is only for Win 10.
You might try it.... can sign up for the newest release.  They need some good user feedback.
Maybe this will help.
ps  windows version available from their sight download only, android from playstore.

Comment: He wants a solution to his current browser, not a suggestion to get a new one.

Comment: @coolbeans2016, welcome to superuser can you add detail on the question asked as your current answer is viewed as promoting a product, 'software' and this site does not support this, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a particular answer for you, but you can try to use the built-in Chrome Task Manager to assist in troubleshooting:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95631?hl=en:

> At the top right, click Menu Menu.
>
> Click More Tools and then Task Manager.

You could also try switching to Chrome Beta build and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the Chrome task manager basically just tells me it's using lots of CPU for pages it's trying to open. Since the problems are similar for Chrome and Firefox, I think it's probably related to Windows 10 somehow.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior for Edge?

Comment: Yes, Edge shows the same problem. I just tried it a minute ago.